# How do I set Apple Calendar to NOT launch when I download an ics file?

Tags: macos, import, calendar, icalendar, launch

IDK what changed but suddenly, everytime I download an ics file my Apple Calendar opens and imports the file. I don't want it to do this but can't figure out what setting to change.

I'm running Yosemite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running *High Sierra*, though I don't recall the option having changed where it can be found.

I'm going to assume that you're using *Safari* web browser, because that's where the setting is that allows MacOS to automatically open certain file types once they've been downloaded by *Safari*.

Open *Safari* preferences by going to the *Safari* menu item and clicking *Preferences...*, or by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (that's a comma) from within a *Safari* window.

If it's not already displayed as the initial pane, click on *General* in the toolbar of the preferences dialog, and you'll see something like this:

[image: Safari Preferences in MacOS]

At the bottom, there's a checkbox that you can uncheck.  Bear in mind that, doing so, will also stop other files you download from opening automatically.  So, for example, if you're used to `.zip` archives being extracted automatically for you, you'll now have to do this manually by double-clicking the `.zip` file (not too hard).

If this solves your issue, consider selecting this answer so it marks the question as being resolved and helps other forum users.  If you have any further problems, however, leave a comment and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Thanks CJK. IDK how that setting got toggled on but once I knew what to look for, it was easily set right. Thanks for the excellent instructions.